# XSD Basic Help Needed -- Namespaces in Schemas?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, xml-validation

I've got something like the following XML file.

```
<credits>
    <property name="tag">
        <item>v0003</item>
    </property>
    <property
        name="tag">
        <item>mhma03h</item>
    </property>
</credits>
```

First requirement is that *this XML cannot change no matter what.* Please don't suggest doing that below.

I need to write a schema that validates this. And Java code that does the validation.

I am completely stuck and I have no idea really what is going on.

What's a schema like this look like? I've gotten one but it's so bad I'm not going to bother posting. :P I don't want to have to append a namespace to the XML elements. They're set in stone.^_^

How do I just make it so all of these elements are just "found" by the parser? Can I just tell it ignore all this namespace nonsense. With this application of validating against a schema, namespace conflicts are simply impossible.

I've tried putting

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="books" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
```

for my namespace info and

**UPDATE:** I've updated what I'm doing to reflect the answers given so far! :)

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="item"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="tag"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="mhma03h"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="v0003"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="credits">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="property" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**


    
        v0003

Code to load and validate yes. Before you ask, the files *are* able to be loaded. I've checked like 20 times. :P

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = 
            SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(
            new Source[] {new StreamSource("small.xsd")}));


        javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        org.xml.sax.XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
        reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
 reader.parse(new InputSource("small.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a schema that corresponds to the XML file you posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by XMLSpy v2011 sp1 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="item"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="tag"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="mhma03h"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="v0003"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="credits">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="property" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This may not correctly capture the requirements for each element and attribute (check that the min/max occurs, required/optional proprerties, etc... are set correctly) but it should get you started on working with an XML schema that will validate correctly. The schema does not define a target namespace so you won't have to worry about modifying the existing XML to add in namespace prefixes to your existing elements.

Comment: I ran your schema through my java validation code and get this exception. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'. Are there specific settings or something I need to set on my SAXParser object for it to not fail?

Comment: This error was because I put .xsd where I should have put .xsl xD

Answer (score -1):

You need to find a way to tell the XML processor to use your namespace as the default when it is processing a document without an explicit namespace.  Most processors have a way to do this, IIRC there is a method named `setNoNamespaceSchema` or something similar.  You would write an XML schema with a namespace and tell the processor (validator, whatever) to use your namespace for documents that do not have an explicit namespace.

Comment: How do a write a schema with a "namespace"?

Comment: Oh, include the [`targetNamespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-0-20041028/#UnqualLocals) attribute on the `xs:schema` element.

Comment: Ok. I've added "targetNamespace=books". I'm using a SAXParser. What option do I set? :D

Comment: >"You need to find a way to tell the XML processor to use your namespace as the default". Eh? No you don't. It's perfectly acceptable to have an instance document with no namespace, described by a no-namespace schema, as given by pmartin. I'm down-voting this reply, it's confusing and wrong, and seems to have further confused the OP.

Comment: Wow. It really has confused me. I've spent the last couple hours looking for a way to do so but couldn't find it. I'm going to update my post with how I'm parsing the XML.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the comment but it's actually confused me more. If I want I'm doing it "perfectly fine" why am I getting "cannot find element credits"?

Comment: @Micheal: you are correct, there are many ways to solve this problem.  Do you plan on providing an answer?  I know that you are quite capable of doing so.  The solution that I mentioned was one that I used with Xerces some years ago to validate a document that used namespaces but did not provide one for the root element.  This worked for me, sorry that it is not the best answer in the world.